# AddressSettings / State & Country picklists translation

Tags: metadata-api, translation, translation-workbench, country-and-state

Question on AddressSettings / State & Country picklists:

Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve translations of country picklist by language via Metadata API / any other exposed salesforce API?
There is an option to translate Address Countries in Translation Workbench, but nothing in Metadata API docs..

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the translation via Metadata API, search for the metadata StandardValueSetTranslation components:

`AddressCountryCode-fr`

`AddressStateCode-fr`

(where `fr` is for French language, but can be replaced if you need another language code).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you expand on this a little? It's a bit confusing as it is.